# Bootstrap: Show on Carousel Product Slider on smallest View only one product

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, carousel

I'm using this example: http://sevenx.de/demo/bootstrap-carousel/inc.carousel/product-slider.html
When I make my BrowserWindow smaller, the boxes first start to be smaller, but when I'm reaching a min width of about 990px, the single Products are arranged among themselves in the 4-block from my start width.
Is it possible to show only ONE product on the max-width: 990px?
Because its not looking good like its now. Sorry, I#m totally new and I don't understand how to set the carousel for my idea.
THANKS A LOT FOR YOUR HELP!

UPDATE: Here is my fiddle:

```
`http://jsfiddle.net/bGwXd/`
```

When you make the RESULT-BLOCK bigger in my fiddle, you see the start view, 4 products in one horizontal line. When you make it smaller, there are 4 products in a vertical line. And now I want only one product in my vertical line for left an right navigation.

Comment: Please create a fiddle/bootply of your problem and provide us with some code of it here in your question.

Comment: I updatet it, here is my fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/bGwXd/

Answer (score 1):

In div .item you have .row and you have 4 .col-md-3 divs you delete the other 3 and leave just one and give it a class .col-md-12. Try with that
Is this what you want? http://jsfiddle.net/bGwXd/1/

```
<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide">
                <div class="carousel-inner">
                    <div class="item active">
                        <div class="row">

                            <div class="col-md-12">
                                <div class="thumbnail">
                                  <img src="http://placehold.it/300x200/" alt="Slide12">
                                  <div class="caption">
                                    <h3>Product label</h3>
                                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor</p>
                                    <p><a href="#" class="btn btn-primary" role="button">12,99 €</a> <a href="#" class="btn btn-default" role="button">Wishlist</a></p>
                                  </div>
                                </div> 
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="item">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-3">
                                <div class="thumbnail">
                                  <img src="http://placehold.it/300x200/" alt="Slide21">
                                  <div class="caption">
                                    <h3>Product label</h3>
                                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor</p>
                                    <p><a href="#" class="btn btn-primary" role="button">12,99 €</a> <a href="#" class="btn btn-default" role="button">Wishlist</a></p>
                                  </div>
                                </div>        
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-3">
                                <div class="thumbnail">
                                  <img src="http://placehold.it/300x200/" alt="Slide22">
                                  <div class="caption">
                                    <h3>Product label</h3>
                                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor</p>
                                    <p><a href="#" class="btn btn-primary" role="button">12,99 €</a> <a href="#" class="btn btn-default" role="button">Wishlist</a></p>
                                  </div>
                                </div> 
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-3">
                                <div class="thumbnail">
                                  <img src="http://placehold.it/300x200/" alt="Slide23">
                                  <div class="caption">
                                    <h3>Product label</h3>
                                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor</p>
                                    <p><a href="#" class="btn btn-primary" role="button">12,99 €</a> <a href="#" class="btn btn-default" role="button">Wishlist</a></p>
                                  </div>
                                </div> 
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-3">
                                <div class="thumbnail">
                                  <img src="http://placehold.it/300x200/" alt="Slide24">
                                  <div class="caption">
                                    <h3>Product label</h3>
                                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor</p>
                                    <p><a href="#" class="btn btn-primary" role="button">12,99 €</a> <a href="#" class="btn btn-default" role="button">Wishlist</a></p>
                                  </div>
                                </div> 
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="item">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-3">
                                <div class="thumbnail">
                                  <img src="http://placehold.it/300x200/" alt="Slide31">
                                  <div class="caption">
                                    <h3>Product label</h3>
                                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor</p>
                                    <p><a href="#" class="btn btn-primary" role="button">12,99 €</a> <a href="#" class="btn btn-default" role="button">Wishlist</a></p>
                                  </div>
                                </div>        
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-3">
                                <div class="thumbnail">
                                  <img src="http://placehold.it/300x200/" alt="Slide32">
                                  <div class="caption">
                                    <h3>Product label</h3>
                                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor</p>
                                    <p><a href="#" class="btn btn-primary" role="button">12,99 €</a> <a href="#" class="btn btn-default" role="button">Wishlist</a></p>
                                  </div>
                                </div> 
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-3">
                                <div class="thumbnail">
                                  <img src="http://placehold.it/300x200/" alt="Slide33">
                                  <div class="caption">
                                    <h3>Product label</h3>
                                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor</p>
                                    <p><a href="#" class="btn btn-primary" role="button">12,99 €</a> <a href="#" class="btn btn-default" role="button">Wishlist</a></p>
                                  </div>
                                </div> 
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-3">
                                <div class="thumbnail">
                                  <img src="http://placehold.it/300x200/" alt="Slide34">
                                  <div class="caption">
                                    <h3>Product label</h3>
                                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor</p>
                                    <p><a href="#" class="btn btn-primary" role="button">12,99 €</a> <a href="#" class="btn btn-default" role="button">Wishlist</a></p>
                                  </div>
                                </div> 
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev"><i class="fa fa-chevron-left fa-2x"></i></a>
                <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next"><i class="fa fa-chevron-right fa-2x"></i></a>

                <ol class="carousel-indicators">
                    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
                    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
                    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
                </ol>                
            </div><!-- End Carousel -->
```

Comment: Thanks for your fiddle, but unfortunately this is not what I want. I want, that only ONE (of all) products is shwon on the smallest side, and not that they are shown verical under.

Answer (score 1):

The carousel works by showing all the items in the row.  Currently, you have 4 items per row, and such they all get displayed.

The view at >990px is responsive to show them 4 in a row horizontal, the view at <990px shows them vertically.

There is no method present in the carousel that allows the view of a single element on it's own without restructuring the html.  You need to add some javascript that will, depending on the size, move the relevant items to their own rows using the carousel callback functions.

Answer (score 1):

I know its late but  someone who came here for help should try [this](http://www.bootply.com/eWhrznPHZq) one :